# Force QMenu to full screen on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qmenu

When deploying a Qt app on Android, application menu (from QMainWindow's QMenuBar) and shown "full-screen" when browsed by user:

[image]

Now, if I create a QMenu dynamically and call exec(), the menu appears small and it's hard to click it:

```
    QMenu menu;
    menu.addAction( new QAction( TextFileWithTime, &menu ) );
    menu.addAction( new QAction( TextFileNoTime, &menu ) );
    menu.addAction( new QAction( BinaryFile, &menu ) );

    QAction* choice = menu.exec();
```

[image]

How can I force the QMenu to go "native" and show full screen as the main window's one does?